# "No timezone found, symbol may be delisted" in Jupiter using get_data_yahoo

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

When I run my code to get stock data from yahoo it keeps returning me "no time zone found, symbol may be delisted". I tried to run the exact same code in Google Colab and it went smoothly, in Jupiter it doesn't.

```
import pytz
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yfin

yfin.pdr_override()
tz = pytz.timezone("America/New_York")
end = tz.localize(dt.datetime.now())
start = tz.localize(dt.datetime(2018, 1, 1))
stocks = ["BRK-B", "V", "JPM", "BAC"]
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stocks, start, end)
df.head()
```

When I tried to run the code in Google Colab it returned a table as expected

`5 rows × 24 columns`

In Jupiter, it keeps returning the same error even though I included the timezone

```
4 Failed downloads:
- V: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted
- JPM: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted
- BAC: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted
- BRK-B: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted
```

Comment: Your code works well on IPython console. Check your versions of pandas_reader and yfinance.

Comment: I see, but if I try to run it everywhere else, like jupyter or pycharm it doesn't work and the same error comes out

Comment: @MatteoP. were you able to sort it out? I am unable to run on jupyter